# Should I store all the data in vuex state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

If I use Vuex, is that means it's better to store every data in the vuex/state?
I have a little confused, some data I get from API (for example UserDetail), I don't need it be shared in components or I counld easily pass it as props.
Should I keep that kind of data in Vuex/State?
Why not get the data by Promise or only use Vuex/Action/Promise?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Data should be kept as local as possible. [That's a general principle that helps reduce complexity](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad). Vuex should handle data that needs to be shared among not-closely-related components.

Comment: If you are using Vuex to transfer state between client and server when doing SSR, it might make sense to put even data that is specific to a single component so that it can be loaded asynchronously right? Or is there a better pattern that I'm missing?

Comment: In that case, I would think of the server as a not-closely-related component.